# как замедлить появление эффекта в javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Хочу что бы при нажатии на кнопку вперед выезжал другой Pane а на старый применялся эффект сепии и это сделать легко, но я не знаю как сделать появление pane и наложение эффекта сеппи плавным... Кто знает помогите пожалуйста..

```
 void handleExit(MouseEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == exitButton) {
            searchPane.setVisible(true);
            searchPane.toFront();
            SepiaTone st = new SepiaTone();
            backgroundImage.setEffect(st);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Вам помогут [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) и [KeyFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html).